# node.js / Where the tmp directory is store?

Tags: node.js, storage

I have a simple upload in the server side:

```
app.post('/saveDocumentChunkData', function (req, res) {
    fs.open(req.files.file.path, 'r', function (status, fd) {
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, contentLength, 0, function (err, bytesRead, buffer1) {
      // do some stuff   
      })
    })
  })
```

Where node.js save the data of the client (`req.files.file.path`)? is it on the RAM? on the disc?

Comment: It's on the disk, wherever `req.files.file.path` is pointing.

Comment: @BenFortune: but I get the req.files.file.path in the request. It doesn't exists on my disc. It exists on the client disc. Where it save on my disc (Server side)?

Comment: It's up to you.  However, since this is server-side code it doesn't really make sense to be opening a file for read on the `POST` handler.

Comment: @Joe:Thanks. And then? if I get the file with ` req.on('data', function(raw) {`, for example, where the data is stored?

Comment: It's not stored.  You have to take that data in the callback and stream it to disk or somewhere.

Comment: @joe: this is right, but as I understand the data is stored somewhere before I save it on disc. This is a stream of bytes, that I have an access to it in order to save it on the disc.  It should be write somewhere on my server machine, before I stream it to disc.

Comment: It's in memory, provided as the `raw` parameter in the `data` callback you posted a few comments up.  It's a chunk of data, the `req.on('data')` callback can be called multiple times as data streams in.

Comment: @Joe: Which memory? RAM? or local disc? I ask it because I want to know if it can handle big files (>10GB). If it store the raw in the RAM it can be problematic.

Comment: This is why it's streaming -- you will get small chunks in each `req.on('data')` callback.  You should be writing these out as they come in, to a file of your own choosing.  When you get `req.on('end')` you will know you've received all of the data for the POST.  This is not like PHP where the entire content is processed and written to a temp file somewhere.  You get handed each bit of data yourself and you have to put it somewhere and concatenate it.